# How to stop the character after walking

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I want my character to stop walking in frame 240 until 600.
But when the animation playing after frame 241. it keeps walking and then the character become weird

[image: Before frame 240]

[image: after frame 240]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots sure, here [link](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/e6JKVKyP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, switch from *Dope Sheet* to *Graph Editor* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>), in the *View* menu, disable *Show Group Colors* to make the channels readable :

[image]

As we can see if you select the root bone, then select its *Y Location* channel, you have enabled the *Linear Extrapolation* on the Y location (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Linear Extrapolation*), which makes it continue indefinitely its movement on this axis. To stop it, choose <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Constant Extrapolation* instead:

[image]

Once done, if you want the character to stop at a certain position on the scene at frame 240, just move it to this position and keyframe.

The fact that some of your character's limbs stretch at the end is because some other bones, like the hands, have been set to *Linear Extrapolation* as well for several of its location channels, so select all these channels and correct that too :

[image]

Comment: i just set all the bone with constant extrapolation. but the hands feet and chest keeps stretching.

Comment: yes because it looks like the Z Location is not the only channel that has been extrapolated, select the 3 location channels and shift E > Constant Extrapolation, your torso also moves, so also correct it, etc...